# How to indirectly set a binding?

Tags: wpf, binding

I've seen enough examples with binding to property `A` with a datacontext where `A` exists in the viewModel class. Now what if in the viewModel I do not have any property `A`, instead I create some calss B that contains property `A`, then how to set up a binding here?

Let's say in xaml`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Bid}"..>` and In the viewModel's constructor I set up

```
Quote b = new Quote();
HttpClient.QuoteMap.Add(1,b);
HttpClient.Socket.reqMktdata(1,contract,..)
```

So `b` keeps updating its `Bid` and `Ask`... The thing is I don't see how to set a binding to `b`'s `Bid`. For `listview` or `DataGrid` I can see how to do it as there's a property called `itemsource` to specify the data binding source and for each column different property is bind to any property if needed.

Comment: anyway the `b` instance should be ***accessible*** inside XAML code if you want to set Binding inside XAML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class itself needs to be a property.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyClassToBind.PublicProperty}"

private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
public MyClass MyClassToBind 
{    get { return  myClass; }  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your viewmodel create a property `A` which has the notify event on its change, but get the data from the `B` instance. If `B` has INotifyPropertyChanged, then subscribe to those changes and when `B` event fires that a change has occurred, post the notified change for your property `A` such as

```
OnPropertyChanged("A");
```

That way you can have related data which exists elsewhere but still updates the view accordingly.

---

This will update when the B property Data changes, to the property `A` on the MVVM.

```
class MyMVVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private TheBClass B { get;  set { OnPropertyChanged("A"); } }

        public string A
        {
            get { return B.Data; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged("A"); }
        }


   public MVVM(TheBClass bInstance;)
   {
      B = bInstance;

      B.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
      {
          if (args.PropertyName == "Data")
             OnPropertyChanged("A");
      };

   }
}
```

Comment: Could you give any makeup simple examples? I don't understand first instance `B` already has property `A` and `A` has INotifyChanged, secondly if I get what you say I need to create a property `C` in the viewModel and subscribe to `A`'s propertychanged in instance `B` which seems not possible as the viewModel and `B` don't know each other..